# Deploy tool for S3

Tags: ruby, git, deployment, amazon-s3, capistrano

We have a desktop application which can be downloaded from S3. 
We are looking for a tool to deploy it, we basically need these functions:
- compile
- create MD5 hash
- upload to s3
- create backups
- make public
- rollback

We are using git, ruby and C++.
Should we use Capistrano + aws-sdk-ruby or that there's a better option?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, you can mount a S3 bucket as a partition and work with S3 files as they where located on your server's HDD.

There are many Linux applications which allow you to do so. You can take a look at my Open source project [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs): a userspace filesystem to mount Amazon S3 buckets.

Hope it helps !